# How to send message and mail in phonegap (ios +android)

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using PhoneGap technology. I need to send text msg and email using PhoneGap. Can you please provide some example how to send text message and email in PhoneGap. I am using (PhoneGap +JQuery) mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below plugins for your application. Working Correctly. I have used months ago in my application.

```
For Android:
```

[SMS Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMSSendingPlugin) and [Email Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/EmailComposerWithAttachments)

and

```
For iOS:
```

[SMS Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/SMSComposer) and [Email Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/EmailComposerWithAttachments)

Comment: They have removed it

Answer (score 1):

1. Download that plugin.
2. Add `emailcomposer.js` file on js files.
3. Add .h and .m file in plugin file.
4. Import messageUI frame.
5. Import plugin in config.
6. Don't forget to add js file in `index.html`.